# PHP: More Efficient Code Equivalent

Tags: php, performance

I'm looking for a more efficient code solution (in PHP) for the code bellow. 
This code is called a lot of times and has been pointed by webgrind as the source of bad performance. (Comparing with all the other components of my code).

```
$xName = "com.company.product";
$xApp = explode(".", $xName);
$xApp = end($xApp);
$xApp = strtoupper($xApp);
```

Example Input: `com.company.product`
Example Output: `PRODUCT`

How should I re-code this to have the same output and be faster? Thank you.

Comment: Out of those 4 lines whats the profile distribution?

Comment: @MikeB 6 milliseconds to process a request and those 4 lines are into a function that appears at the top of `self cost`.

Comment: I meant what's the % cost across those lines? Which one takes the most time compared to the others? i.e. explode() takes 50% while end and strtoupper are closer to 25 each.

Comment: @MikeB `explode()` was definitely the source of the problem. This is fixed now using Jasper solution but thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure of the performance difference but you can use `strrpos` to get the position of the last period and then use `substr` to get everything after that position:

```
$xName  = "com.company.product";
$dotPos = strrpos($xName, ".");
$xApp   = strtoupper(substr($xName, $dotPos + 1));
```

I'd imagine this is quicker than exploding a string.

Here's the PHP documentation for `strrpos`: http://www.php.net/strrpos

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot about that one ;) I'll test that one in production for the next hours and check the performance.

Comment: @TCB13 I'll be interested to see the performance difference, better or worse. If you can, please report back what you find.

Comment: I just tested this with `10000000` iterations (with the same `$xName`). This one took `10.53` seconds, while the original version took `16.78` seconds. Clearly, this is faster.

Comment: @Jasper your solution is clearly faster, I just tried to process stored records in a DB and I got similar results as Amal Murali . Thank you :)